# Cloudfront wordpress apache too many redirect

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-cloudfront

I am setting out wordpress with apache and cloudfront.

My portal is hosted at xxx.cloudfront.net/blog

When I serve with cloudfront address at xxx.cloudfront.net/blog, it fails with error too many redirect.

When i serve with my server ip at myserviceip/blog, it works fine.

It would work if i explicity put  indexphp into the cloudfront url as follow **xxx.cloudfront.net/blog/index.php** but I don't want the index.php be there.

Where should I configure this so that it work without index.php in the url? Apache and/or cloudfront and how should I configure it?

Comment: Sounds like Wordpress does try to redirect to the Site Url that is configured, but the redirection doesn't work. Maybe check the site url?

Comment: What is the nature of the redirect loop? Form/to?